# PHP - set variable name

Tags: php

I have a variable `$item='name'`. I want to create a new variable called `$nameError`.

Because `$item` changes through each loop I would like to set this like: `$$itemError` however I know this syntax is incorrect.

Can anyone let me know the correct way to do this?

Comment: You're probably looking for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). For partial varvar names you'd use `${"{$item}Error"} = "...";` - What you actually *ought to be using* is an array however.

Comment: @mario Just: `${$item . "Error"}` is enough :)